# Specific field in filterset_class

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have Student Model and I need to filter students who don't have personal trainers using `filterset_class`

```
models.py

class Student(models.Model):
    personal_trainer = models.ForeignKey(PersonalTrainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

views.py

class StudentsView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StudentsSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    pagination_class = None
```

and here is the `views.py`

```
class StudentFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    has_personal_trainer = rest_framework.BooleanFilter(field_name="personal_trainer", lookup_expr="isnull")

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("has_personal_trainer")

class StudentsView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StudentsSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = (rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = StudentFilter
```

when I use the request with `api/students?care_navigator=false` it gives me the following error massege

```
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'has_personal_trainer' into field. Choices are: personal_trainer, personal_trainer_id`
```

etc...

Comment: With the current modeling, *all* students have a `personal_trainer`, since the field is non-NULLable.

Comment: my bad, forgot to add those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FilterSet` class.

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework

class StudentFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    has_personal_trainer = rest_framework.BooleanFilter(field_name="personal_trainer", lookup_expr="isnull")

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("has_personal_trainer",)
```

In views.py

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework

class StudentsView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StudentsSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = (rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = StudentFilter
```

Usage
`api/students?has_personal_trainer=true` or `api/students?has_personal_trainer=false`

Comment: I tried to have api/students?care_navigator=isnull but it says that Field 'id' expected a number but got 'isnull'.

Comment: What is the car_navigator ? I've updated my answer and added usage, you can check it

Comment: I tried that way but now it says django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'has_personal_trainer' into field.

Comment: Could you update your question with your code and full traceback of error

Comment: alright it worked, thank you so much.